# Is there a replaceWholeText Equivalent in jQuery? - How to replace TextNode

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to replace only the textNode of an element without destroying any child DOM elements?

```
<a href="#"><span>Text we don't want replaced</span> Text we want replaced</a>
```

When using `jquery.text([content])` it will replace any child nodes as well as the text content. Thus resulting in...

```
<a href="#">Replaced Text</a>
```

To get around this issue, I use the javascript function: replaceWholeText, but is there a better more jQuery-esque way of doing this?

```
$('a.button')[0].lastChild.replaceWholeText('Replacement Text');
```

Second question: Will this work in all browsers?

jsfiddle example showing both the jQuery and Javascript methods:
http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/ABfMS/1/

Comment: *"Second question: Will this work in all browsers?"* Best to ask **one** question at a time. The question of whether jQuery has such a thing, and whether `replaceWholeText` is reliable cross-browser, are very different questions with different answers.

Comment: The answer to the second question, I discovered, is No, it will not work in all browsers. It's better to use `$('a.button')[0].lastChild.nodeValue = 'Replacement Text'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but is there a better more jQuery-esque way of doing this?

jQuery doesn't offer a *specific* method for doing that, no.

Answer (score -1):

Nettuts+ wrote an article on the replaceText jquery plugin developed by [Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-jquery-replacetext/

Comment: hm. am still young and impulsive i guess :o) sorry for my missunderstanding